# AngularJS - How would I extract two pieces of data from a json response and use them in a select (combobox)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, factory

I am making a http.get request to retrieve a list of airports. The json response contains lots of data. It returns a list of objects in the following format

```
{"id":"1","name":"Goroka","city":"Goroka","country":"Papua New Guinea","iata":"GKA","icao":"AYGA","latitude":"-6.081689","longitude":"145.391881","altitude":"5282","timezone":"10","dst":"U","tz":"Pacific/Port_Moresby"}
```

I would like to extract the country and iata and display them in a select on my html page e.g.

Papua New Guinea GKA
Greenland UAK
...

I have already created an array of objects with these two pieces of data (in a factory) and returned it to my array, but I do not know how to display two pieces of data in a select.

Comment: Can you share more code please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use ng-options directive on the select statement.

Assuming your array of data contains objects like this:

```
$scope.airports = [{id:1,name:"Papa New Guinea",iata: "GKA"},...]
```

You can display them in a select as follows:

```
<select ng-model="selectedAirport" ng-options="(itm.name + ' ' + itm.iata) for itm in airports"></select>
```

Here's a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1M1mwvSb6YDSWhQ52MdJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ng-options` directive, which is specifically for using `ng-repeat` behaviour on a `select` element: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions. For example, assuming that your array of airports can be retrieved synchronously, in your controller:

```
module.controller('ctrl', function($scope, Airports) {
    $scope.airports = Airports.get();
    $scope.$watch('airportId', function(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
    });
});
```

In your template, taking advantage of Angular's expression parsing:

```
<select ng-options="for item in airports" ng-model="airportId">
    <option value="item.id" ng-bind="item.country + ' ' + item.iata"></option>
</select>
```

Alternatively, print the values inside the `option` element:

```
<select ng-options="for item in airports" ng-model="airportId">
    <option value="item.id">{{item.country}} {{item.iata}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the properties:

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

                <select ng-model="model.id" ng-options='note.id as (note.name+" "+note.iata) for note in notes' ></select>

                {{model.iata}}

            </div>

        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7eqsc/146/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clear the returned JSON, you can use `ng-options` and print only what you need:

```
<body ng-app="selectExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('selectExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.airports = [{
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Goroka",
          "city": "Goroka",
          "country": "Papua New Guinea",
          "iata": "GKA",
          "icao": "AYGA",
          "latitude": "-6.081689",
          "longitude": "145.391881",
          "altitude": "5282",
          "timezone": "10",
          "dst": "U",
          "tz": "Pacific/Port_Moresby"
        }, {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "RAF Cranwell",
          "city": "Coningsby",
          "country": "Lincolhshire",
          "iata": "QCY",
          "icao": "EGXC",
          "latitude": "",
          "longitude": "",
          "altitude": "",
          "timezone": "10",
          "dst": "U",
          "tz": ""
        }];
      }]);
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <label>Airport:
      <select ng-model="selectedAirport" ng-options="airport.name + ' - ' + airport.iata for airport in airports"></select>
    </label>
    <pre>
        {{selectedAirport}}
    </pre>
    <br/>
  </div>
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fNJkZsRkA06EgxnRjLUQ?p=preview